# What is the purpose of the "Miracle" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A [recent question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/42885/43337) used the tag [miracle](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miracle) for a claim that a religious person improbably escaped from a maximum security prison. Based on the links the question provides, it seems that the event is indeed described as a miracle, or at least "miraculous", by various religious sources.

In the comments for the question, the following point was brought up:

> Not sure about the attribution to / tag of "miracle". This would make any answer in the affirmative, "he did escape without help", basically a concession to spiritual belief.

I personally think that the point raised by the comment is stronger than is merited, and that answers could very reasonably provide evidence that the escape happened, that it did not happen, or that it happened under circumstances very different from the ones claimed, and doing so wouldn't need to involve assertions related to miracles at all. However, if that *is* the case, then I'm not certain that the [miracle](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miracle) tag accomplishes anything; it identifies that something was claimed to be a miracle, but I don't think that determining *if* something is a miracle would be on-topic, and I don't think being called a miracle would change how it is investigated otherwise.

Thus, I'm trying to ascertain the purpose of the tag and possibly whether it should be removed or changed. The [tag wiki](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/miracle/info) offers mainly a definition of the term rather than usage guidelines. So, do answers to questions with the tag [miracle](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miracle) implicitly confirm or deny the existence of miracles? Is the it even useful? What questions, if any, should it be on?

Comment: Thanks for picking this up; I've been mulling this over myself but didn't get around to take it to meta. ;-)